# Selenium Python Using find elements how do i get the text value of each element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver with Python.
I have a search results page which displays a list of products.
I want to loop through the list and print out the text value of the h2 tag.
E.g. it should print out F1 2015 (PS4)
I know i should use self.driver_find_elements to get all the elements into a list.
I should then use a for loop to iterate through and print out it's value.
My code is not working.  It prints out a list of the representation of the object.  It does not print out F1 2015 (PS4)

This is my selenium python code:

```
 def click_search(self):
    search_field = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="twotabsearchtextbox"]')
    search_field.send_keys("F1")
    search_button = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, './/*[@id="nav-search"]/form/div[2]/div/input').click()
    searchresults_text = self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@class="a-row a-spacing-small"]//a/h2')
    print searchresults_text
    for i in searchresults_text:
        print searchresults_text
```

The html snippet is:

```
<div class="a-row a-spacing-small">
<a class="a-link-normal s-access-detail-page a-text-normal"  href="http://localhost:8080/testurl/i=1437258749&sr=8-1&keywords=f1" title="F1 2015 (PS4)">
<h2 class="a-size-medium a-color-null s-inline s-access-title a-text-normal">F1 2015 (PS4)</h2>
</a>
```

The output to the console is:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0282F290>,       
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0282F2B0>,     
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x0282F2D0>]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First elements of `searchresults_text` are bound to `i` but you never use it and try to print `searchresults_text` instead. Moreover to get text content you can use `text` property:

```
for el in searchresults_text:
   print el.text
```

Comment: That is brilliant.  It works now.  I get the desired output now.  F1 2015 (PS4)
F1 2015, F1 2014 (PS3), F1 2013 (PS3), F1 2012 (Xbox 360), 
F1 2011 (Xbox 360).  Thanks very much.